# My first proof employing strong induction / complete induction (very simple number theory). Please mark/grade.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-writing, induction, proof-verification

What do you think about my first proof employing strong induction? What mark/grade would you give me?

---

### Theorem

Every natural number greater than 1 is a product of one or more primes.

### Proof

First, introducing a predicate $P$ over $\mathbb{N}$, we rephrase the theorem as follows.
        $$\forall n \in \{2, 3, \dots \}, \, P(n)
  \quad \text{where} \quad
  P(n) \, := \, n \text{ is a product of one or more primes}$$
        We prove the theorem by strong induction; we induct on $n$.

#### Basis

We have $P(n)$ for $n = 2$, since $2$ is a product of one prime, namely $2$.

#### Inductive step

Below, we show that for all
            $n \in \{2, 3, \dots \}$,
            $$P(2) \land \dots \land P(n - 1) \land P(n) \Rightarrow P(n + 1)\text{.}$$

Let $k \in \{2, 3, \dots \}$.
            We assume that $P(2) \land \dots \land P(k - 1) \land P(k)$ is true.
            In the following, we use this assumption to show that $P(k + 1)$ is true.

We consider $k + 1$.
            There are two cases: It is prime or not.
            Obviously, the cases are exhaustive.
            We consider the cases separately;
            in each consideration, we conclude that $P(k + 1)$ is true.
            In so doing, we conclude the inductive step for all cases.

**Case 1:**
    Obviously, $k + 1$ is a product of one prime, namely $k + 1$.
            Thus $P(k + 1)$ is true.

**Case 2:**
    As $k + 1$ is not prime, by definition,
            it may be represented as a product of at least two natural numbers
            that are greater than $1$.
Thus there are $i, j \in \{2, \dots, k - 1, k\}$ such that $ij = k + 1$.
            By the induction hypothesis, $P(i)$ and $P(j)$ are true.
            Hence, we can easily see that the product $\,ij\,$ is a product of primes.
            Thus $P(ij)$ is true. (Thus $P(k + 1)$ is true.)

By the basis, the inductive step, and the method of strong induction;
        $P(n)$ is true for all $n \in \{2, 3, \dots \}$.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: I don't like strong induction. Can you rewrite this as a 'simple' induction?

Comment: Your proof is fine, 10/10. Styles differ, but it is more common to use the following notation. We show that for all $n$, if $P(k)$ is true for all $k\lt n$, then $P(n)$ is true.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thanks, I will keep the notation in mind.

Comment: You are welcome. Please note there is absolutely nothing wrong with your proof. There are two reasons to proceed from all less than $n$ to $n$: (i) Tradition and (ii) It fits in better with *structural* induction.

Comment: @mookid: I suppose not. Do you think that 'simple' induction should be used for this problem?

Comment: you can always convert a strong induction to a 'simple' induction. Just replace the property "$P(n)$" with "for every $k\le n, P(k)$".

Comment: My point is, you don't have to think there is anything different with a strong induction. Just be precise when writing what $P(n)$ is.

Comment: @mookid: I see! Thanks, that really helped me.